# Variable not taking on values in C#

Tags: c#, xml, variables

I have the following problem -

```
rec = new Record(name, age, dob, sex, country );
webservicename.function[] test = new webservicename.function[1];
test[0].name = rec.name;
test[i].age = rec.age;
test[i].dob = dob;
test[i].sex = sex;
test[i].country = country;
```

When I start debugging it stops on the first test[0] line with a 'NullReferenceException was uhandled' message. When I hover mouse over the rec.Account it shows the value from the csv file that I have read from, however when I hover over test[0] its value is null. For some reason the variable array is not taking on values, How can I sort this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `rec.Account` do you mean `rec.name`?

Comment: what's singlesummary[1] ? and why use index 0 and index i ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
rec = new Record(name, age, dob, sex, country );
webservicename.singlesummary[] test = new webservicename.singlesummary[1];
webservicename.singlesummary result = new webservicename.singlesummary();
result.account = rec.name;
result.actualy = rec.age;
result.commitment = dob;
result.costCentre = sex;
result.internalCostCentre = country;
test[0] = result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the instance first:

```
rec = new Record(name, age, dob, sex, country ); 
webservicename.singlesummary[] test = new webservicename.singlesummary[1]; 
test[0] = new webservicename.singlesummary(); // extra line for your code
test[0].name= rec.name; 
test[0].age = rec.age; 
test[0].dob = dob; 
test[0].sex = sex; 
test[0].country = country;
```

Obvously, if you need an array and you have length greater than one, you could replace all but lines one and two above inside a for...next loop and index to the `ith` element.

I notice though, that you're indexing into the array with `[0]` (and creating an array of length 1) which seems pointless to me, you might as well use a single instance:

```
rec = new Record(name, age, dob, sex, country ); 
webservicename.singlesummary test = new webservicename.singlesummary(); 
test.name= rec.name; 
test.age = rec.age; 
test.dob = dob; 
test.sex = sex; 
test.country = country;
```

If the reason you're using an array of length one is because the service you call only accepts an array/list of items, you can always create one during the call:

```
wbsvcProxy.MethodCall(new List<singlesummary>() { test });
```

In my opinion, this is more readable throughout your code, since you only build the array/list when you're calling the method and removes all of the funky `[0].` syntax from the rest of your code (If your method doesn't require it, then never mind this last bit)

Comment: sorry I had to edit the question I made a mistake if yo could look at the update would appreciate it

Comment: I have seen your edit, review my code. I'm doing two things, first I initialize the array, second I initialize the zeroth `[0]` item in the array as well. You need to do both steps if you're using an array.